# Executable runs without sudo privileges under one account, but not another?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

So I have an executable that uses some 3rd party serial device drivers.  I can run it on one account (non-root) without the sudo command, however on an account I just created it requires sudo otherwise it can't access the serial device (still have to dig deeper on that).  I did use the command 'usermod -aG sudo username' so the sudo command allows it to work, but something is different in permissions with these accounts.

Only thing I can think of is I used insmod/modprobe under the original account to insert the *.ko module file, maybe the permissions for the module need to be changed to read from all users?

Comment: Did you restart the system after the creation?

Comment: Are both users in the `dialout` group?

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions of the executable, where is it located, and what does it do ?

Comment: Yes the system has been restarted.  I am unfamiliar with the dailout group, I'll go ahead and look it up and check.  Regarding the executable, it's a really simple program that I wrote and compiled that just opens up a serial connection.  I have actually compiled it under both users, and verified that the original user can run it without sudo in both account directories and the new account can only run either executable with the sudo command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@steeldriver got me on the right track.  I used the command 'groups originaluser' and 'groups newuser' to compare what groups they belonged to.  I had to add the 'adm' group to the new user in order to access the serial port.